How to log to Stackify in .NET7 application
I have a .NET 7 application and I tried to logs to Stackify without success.
I didn't found any solution on any site and I need your help.
I will just mention that in .NET 7 we have only progarm.cs file without startup.cs file.
Please show me what should I add to my program.cs file, appsetting.json file, myService.cs file and so on.. So I can see logs in my Stackify dashboard
Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
